# fread and fwrite in matlab not exact

Tags: matlab, binary, precision, fwrite, fread

I would like to save float numbers in a binary file and read them afterwards for further processing. Unfortunately, fwrite and afterwards fread does change the number.

Following simple example:

```
% Number to store
A = 0.123456789101112

% Generate and open txt file
fid = fopen('test_fread.txt','w','b');

% write A into test_fread.txt
fwrite(fid,A,'float32');

% close file
fclose(fid)

% open txt file
fid = fopen('test_fread.txt','r','b');

% read the file
fread(fid,'float32')

ans = 0.123456791043282
```

The answer is different than the input. How can I fix this? What should I search for? Is it rounding, precision or another problem?

Comment: 32 bit floats [only have 6-9 decimals of precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). If you need more precision one option is to multiply by a known power of 10 and save the value as an appropriately sized integer, with the caveat that MATLAB's default data type, `double` only has 15-17 significant decimal digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point numbers [are never exact](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). `single` precision floats (`float32`) [only have 6-9 decimals of precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). For the pure decimal case this translates to the issue that you're seeing. The effect is more exaggerated if you also have an integer component:

```
% Sample number
A = 123456789.123456789;

% Write, rewind, and read back in
fID = fopen('test_fread.txt', 'w+', 'b');
fwrite(fID, A, 'float32');
frewind(fID);
B = fread(fID,'float32');
fclose(fID);

fprintf('A: %15.15f\nB: %15.15f\n', A, B);
```

Which returns:

```
A: 123456789.123456790000000
B: 123456792.000000000000000
```

Note that MATLAB casts `B` as a `double` here.

MATLAB's default data type, `double` (`float64`) has double the bits available, which will give you [15-17 significant decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Using the previous example we can try:

```
% Sample number
A = 123456789.123456789;

% Write, rewind, and read back in
fID = fopen('test_fread.txt', 'w+', 'b');
fwrite(fID, A, 'float64');
frewind(fID);
B = fread(fID,'float64');
fclose(fID);

fprintf('A: %15.15f\nB: %15.15f\n', A, B);
```

Which returns:

```
A: 123456789.123456790000000
B: 123456789.123456790000000
```

Yay.

If you need better precision in MATLAB than `double` you will need to look into using [`vpa`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html), which is part of the Symbolic Math Toolbox, or a similar package that offers higher/variable precision.